# how to prove this function is harmonic (Fritz John 4.1 #5)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The problem is to prove that Kelvin transformation preserves harmonic functions. That is

If $u$ is a harmonic function, then $v(x)=|x|^{2-n}u(\frac{x}{|x|^2})$ is harmonic whenever it is defined.

I know there is a way to calculate $\Delta v$ explicitly ($\Delta v=|x|^{-n-2}\Delta u(x/|x|^2)$), which will give me the conclusion. But I was told that this fact can be proven easily by using the fact that if $\int_{\Omega}\langle \nabla v,\nabla \phi\rangle dx=0$, for any test function $\phi$ with $\phi|_{\partial \Omega}=0$, then $v$ is harmonic.

So I calculated $\nabla v$ and yielded that it is equal to 
$$(2-n)|x|^{-n}u(\frac{x}{|x|^2})x+|x|^{-n}\nabla u(\frac{x}{|x|^2})-2|x|^{-2-n}(\nabla u(\frac{x}{|x|^2})\cdot x)x $$
Then I don't know what to do. Can somebody give any idea how this should work?